# ConstraintLayout version is obsolete

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In the Component Tree window,when I  right-click the layout and click Convert layout to `ConstraintLayout` ,the following error occurred:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file update `ConstraintLayout` version as below

**compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'**

Comment: the have released new version 1.0.1. You can ignore that error since there will be frequent updates.

Comment: I think there is a bug with 1.0.1. switch back to 1.0.0 and use it until fix is available

Comment: e,It's available.ths